# Android Kotlin Multiselect dropdown

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to implement a multi-select dropdown like the image below with the arrow at the end & selected items showing in the text field ( marquee if needed). Can someone help?
I don't want it to pop up like a dialog box, but to open under the textview like a normal spinner.

[multi select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Lk8V.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a spinner in your own xml and create a custom adapter for that spinner that will take an array as a parametre

You can follow these

[Multi Select Spinner - GitHub Repo](https://trinitytuts.com/tips/multiselect-spinner-item-in-android/)

[Multiselect Spinner](https://trinitytuts.com/tips/multiselect-spinner-item-in-android/)

[Step by step development of MultiselectSpinner](https://trinitytuts.com/tips/multiselect-spinner-item-in-android/)

Comment: While these links may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the links you provided show the "multiselect Spinner" as a  pop up dialog. do you know any other way to just open a normal dropdown spinner?

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the official google's documentation - https://material.io/components/menus/android

After adding items to the menu, add a drawable icon in the same.

Comment: I'm not sure if its possible to select multiple options in menu. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: This sadly only works for single select and they prevented the ability to stop dismiss starting Android 12 (who knows why...)

Answer (score -1):

Handle visibility of selected item view in custom way.

I have made some changes in Spinner Adapter for handling multiple selection, Try below code:

> Spinner Adapter  (MultiSelectionSpinnerAdapter.kt)

```
class MultiSelectionSpinnerAdapter(var context: Context?, var spinnerList: List<String>?, val multipleSelectionCallBack:MultipleSelectionCallBack) : BaseAdapter() {

    private var TAG = MultiSelectionSpinnerAdapter::class.java.simpleName
    private var selectedItemsList: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
    fun setSelectedItemsList(selectedItemsList: ArrayList<String>) {
        this.selectedItemsList = selectedItemsList
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
    private val inflater: LayoutInflater = context!!.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {

        val view: View
        val vh: ItemHolder
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_multi_selection_spinner, parent, false)
            vh = ItemHolder(view)
            view?.tag = vh
        } else {
            view = convertView
            vh = view.tag as ItemHolder
        }
        try {
            vh.tvSpinnerText.text = spinnerList!![position]
        }catch (e:Exception){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        if (selectedItemsList.size > 0) {
            for (i in selectedItemsList.indices) {
                if (selectedItemsList[i] == spinnerList!![position]) {
                    vh.llSpinnerSelected.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    break
                }else{
                    vh.llSpinnerSelected.visibility = View.GONE
                }
            }
        }

        view.setOnClickListener {
            val selectedItemText = spinnerList!![position]
            if(vh.llSpinnerSelected.visibility == View.VISIBLE){
                vh.llSpinnerSelected.visibility = View.GONE
                multipleSelectionCallBack.onItemSelect(false, selectedItemText, position)
            }else{
                vh.llSpinnerSelected.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                multipleSelectionCallBack.onItemSelect(true, selectedItemText, position)
            }
        }
        return view
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Any? {
        return spinnerList!![position]
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return spinnerList!!.size
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return position.toLong()
    }

    private class ItemHolder(row: View?) {
        val tvSpinnerText: TextView
        val llSpinnerSelected: LinearLayout

        init {
            tvSpinnerText = row?.findViewById(R.id.tvSpinnerText) as TextView
            llSpinnerSelected = row?.findViewById(R.id.llSpinnerSelected) as LinearLayout
            llSpinnerSelected.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    }

    interface MultipleSelectionCallBack{
        fun onItemSelect(isSelect:Boolean, selectedItemText:String, position: Int)
    }
}
```

> Spinner Item Layout (item_multi_selection_spinner.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSpinnerText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/llSpinnerSelected"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="14sp"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llSpinnerSelected"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="5dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/bg_selected_item"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

> Activity Code:

```
class YourActivityName : AppCompatActivity(),
    MultiSelectionSpinnerAdapter.MultipleSelectionCallBack {
    val items = ArrayList<String>()
    lateinit var multiSpinner:Spinner
    lateinit var  multiSelectionSpinnerAdapter : MultiSelectionSpinnerAdapter
    private var selectedItemsList: java.util.ArrayList<String> = java.util.ArrayList()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_name)
        multiSpinner = findViewById<View>(R.id.multiSpinner) as Spinner

        items.add("A")
        items.add("B")
        items.add("C")
        items.add("D")
        items.add("E")
        multiSelectionSpinnerAdapter = MultiSelectionSpinnerAdapter(this, items, this)
        multiSpinner.adapter = multiSelectionSpinnerAdapter
    }
    override fun onItemSelect(isSelect: Boolean, selectedItemText: String, position: Int) {
        if(isSelect){
            //Add object to your selected list
        }else{
            //remove object from your selected list
        }
        Log.e("onItemSelect----","-=:${selectedItemsList.size}")
        multiSelectionSpinnerAdapter.setSelectedItemsList(selectedItemsList)
    }
}
```

You can handle data according to your requirement in `onItemSelect()` method

Output for Multiple Selected Spinner is:

[image]